# Prevent linearlayout pushing elements from its side in horizontal orientation

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have a `LinearLayout` with orientation `horizontal` and I don't want my first `TextView` to push the other ones, this is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TEST asdas asd" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_qty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Qty: 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:text="$100.00"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Output

With not so much text it looks like this

[image]

But when the text increases there is a problem... the first `TextView` pushes all other text views and I want to keep the aspect of the first image if the first text just increases I want to give it a line and not push adjacent text.

[image]

Comment: Try to give weight and padding to your TextViews so that TextViews will not expand beyond that.And to show dotted line at end use android:ellipsize="end" android:maxLines="1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a problem with the layout. You are setting the weights of your items, but you have the `layout_width` set to `wrap_content` which is contradictory with the `layout_weight`. Hence I would recommend modifying the layout as follows (basically setting the `layout_width=0dp`).

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Some long text that is pushing the other texts to the right and taking up all the spaces!!!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_qty"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Qty: 2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="$100.00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: it seems the linear layout wrap height is not wraping all the text, what should I do to wrap all the text?

Comment: I would try putting some margins to top and bottom. Please let me know if that works.

Comment: Great to know that I could help! Happy coding and stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you're using weights you have to set layout_height to 0 for linear layout with orientation vertical. While layout_width to 0 for horizontal linearr layout.